# How to scan a string for its contents to see whether it contains uppercase or lowercase characters

Tags: linux, string, bash

Hello I am trying to make a password generator that scans a string to see whether it contains uppercase or lowercase characters. The contents of the string are generated using a bank of characters to use

```
char=(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V X W Y Z)

   #chars=(~ ! @ # $ % ^ & * - +)                                     
####rand2=$random % 11


   max=${#char[*]}    for i in `seq 1 $pwdlen`
      do
           let "rand=$RANDOM % $max"
                  str="${str}${char[$rand]}"
      done    echo $str    exit 0 fi str=$1 len=${#str}

if [ $len -lt 8 ] then
        echo $str is too short fi if [ $len -gt 16 ] then
        echo $str is too long fi
```

Comment: Are you still looking for a password generator with lowercase characters, at least one uppercase character, only one number, special characters and a length of 8-16?

Comment: Just need to figure out how to add a single character from a bank @ #  $  %  &  *  +  -  = anywhere randomly to the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check with a regular expression (regex) if string contains at least one upper case character:

```
if [[ "$str" =~ [[:upper:]] ]]; then
  echo "uppercase character found"
fi
```

To check with a regex if string contains at least one lower case character:

```
if [[ "$str" =~ [[:lower:]] ]]; then
  echo "lowercase character found"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `bash` case conversion operations.

```
if [[ $passwd = ${passwd,,} ]]; then
  echo "$passwd" has no upper-case letters
fi

if [[ $passwd = ${passwd^^} ]]; then
  echo "$passwd" has no lower-case letters
fi
```

The first expression -- `${passwd,,}` -- converts all upper-case letters to lower-case letters, so if it doesn't change anything, there were no upper-case letters. Similarly, `${passwd^^}` converts lower-case to upper-case.

Requires bash 4.

Answer (score 0):

To check if string contains at least 1 upper case character:

```
[[ "$str" == *[[:upper:]]* ]] && echo "one uppercase character exists"
```

To check if string contains at least 1 lower case character:

```
[[ "$str" == *[[:lower:]]* ]] && echo "one lowercase character exists"
```

Answer (score 0):

try using ascii character codes on your conditional filter.. works in other situations too where you need to check for numbers, lowercase chars, etc

```
echo $password | while read -n1 char
do
  ascii_code=$(printf "%d\n" \'$char)
  if [ $ascii_code -ge 65 ] && [ $ascii_code -le 90 ]; then
    echo "Found $char : $ascii_code"
  fi
done
```